# Changing text in running dialog

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using custom layout for my dialog which contains progressbar and textview. I want to change the text in dialog if its already running. This is my code for doing this operation.

```
private static Dialog progressDialog = null;
public static void showLoadingProgress(String msg){
        Log.d("Util", "show loading progress"+progressDialog);//No i18n
        if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            TextView message = (TextView)progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressmsg);
            message.setText(msg);           
        }else{          
            progressDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customprogress);

            TextView message = (TextView)progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressmsg);
            message.setText(msg);

            progressDialog.show();
            Log.d("",progressDialog.isShowing()+""); //No i18n
        }
    }

    public static void hideLoadingProgress(){
        Log.d("Util", "close loading progress"+progressDialog);//No i18n

        if(progressDialog!=null){
        Log.d("ProgressDialog is not null, so making it null",""); //No i18n  
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
```

Am calling this method from try block and in catch block from asyncTask doInBackground(). First calling from try block shows dialog, but if any error occurs, again call from catch block happens and throws this Exception

```
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6313)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3567)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
03-26 13:42:53.002: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 2):

you should call those methods on the `MainThread` ( `UIThread` : ***the only thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*** ) , if you call them on a separated `thread` you should call them by using the method : `runOnUiThread()` :

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showLoadingProgress("Loading data...");
            }
        });
```

**EDIT** : and here is a [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/) that display a `ProgressDialog` while downloading a file from server,  i think it's exactly what you want , take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to "change" your text and progress dialog, by overriding onProgressUpdate() of your AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
        // Do your change here with your own data
    }
```

doInBackground() is supposed to perform a computation on a background thread.